# SVD using Scikit-Learn and Gensim with 6 million features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gensim, svd

I am trying to classify paragraphs based on their sentiments. I have training data of 600 thousand documents. When I convert them to `Tf-Idf` vector space with words as analyzer and ngram range as 1-2 there are almost 6 million features. So I have to do Singular value decomposition (SVD) to reduce features.

I have tried gensim and sklearn's SVD feature. Both work fine for feature reduction till 100 but as soon as I try for 200 features they throw memory error.

Also I have not used entire document (600 thousand) as training data, I have taken 50000 documents only. So essentially my training matrix is:
50000 * 6 million and want to reduce it to  50000 * (100 to 500)

Is there any other way I can implement it in python, or do I have to implement sparks mllib SVD(written for only java and scala) ? If Yes, how much faster will it be?

System specification: 32 Gb RAM with 4 core processors on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see why using sparks mllib SVD would improve performance or avoid memory errors. You simply exceed the size of your RAM. You have some options to deal with that:

- Reduce the dictionary size of your tf-idf (playing with max_df and min_df parameters of scikit-learn for example).
- Use a hashing vectorizer instead of tf-idf.
- Get more RAM (but at some point tf-idf + SVD is not scalable).

Also you should show your code sample, you might do something wrong in your python code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I should play around with the max_df and min_df parameter. Also I haven't looked at hashing vectorizer yet so I will see what I can do with it.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar scenario but doesn't Spark do distributed training so shouldn't that help with the memory issue ? Also @dudefrmbgr did you end up getting a solution to make it work for all the documents ? I would love to know things like that worked and how much time it takes